# Remove "uniqueness" from SQL table's row

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I can easily add uniqueness to a row from the sql web interface phpMyAdmin, but how can I remove it?

It's not clickable in the interface, and I can't find anything in the mysql documentation.

Any help?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename DROP INDEX(indexname);`

Comment: @Wrikken why not make it an answer instead?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( rowname )' at line 1

Comment: Sorry guys, but I really don't understand why this "isn't a real question". It could help someone who is facing the same issue, so I'm not deleting it. If you can tell me how I could reword the question so to match your will, I'll edit my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be Wrikken's answer - not sure why he hasn't posted it yet ...

Considering the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
(
some_id int NOT NULL,
someColumn varchar(255) NOT NULL
UNIQUE (some_id )
)
```

You would want to use:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP INDEX some_id;
```

Drop index does just what it sounds like, it completely removes an index from a table.

See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop.asp)

Comment: same thing here, i get this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( columnname )' at line 1

Comment: Solved. Apparently the right syntax it's ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP INDEX some_id; not ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP INDEX(some_id); do you agree with that?

Comment: @domenicop sorry about that, I had it there just to let you know to *change* it :)